# What is the proper terminology for each type of an identifier?

Tags: c#, oop, terminology

Take the following code:

```
IFoo foo = new FooImplementation();
```

The identifier `foo` has two types:

1. `IFoo` - This is the type the compiler will enforce.  I will only be able to call methods that are part of the `IFoo` contract, otherwise I'll get a compiler error.
2. `FooImplementation` - This is the type as known by the runtime.  I can downcast `foo` to a `FooImplementation` at runtime, and then call non-IFoo methods of `FooImplementation`.

**My question:** What is the proper terminology for these two types.  I could *swear* in school we were taught that `IFoo` is the identifier's *static type* and `FooImplementation` is its *dynamic type*, but after much searching on Google I can't seem to find any reference to this.

Comment: `IFoo` is the type of variable foo. `FooImplementation` is the type of memory allocated to foo.

Comment: Not sure why I got a downvote.  I think this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call `IFoo` and `FooImplementation` the compile-time and run-time types, respectively. This language is used by C# spec, for example, when talking about virtual methods (section 1.6.6.4):

> When a virtual method is invoked, the **run-time type** of the instance for which that invocation takes place determines the actual method implementation to invoke. In a nonvirtual method invocation, the **compile-time type** of the instance is the determining factor.

Comment: `+1` for the language spec reference.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Mike Z. The usual terminology in C# is "compile time type" and "runtime type".

"Static type" and "dynamic type" are entirely reasonable terms but I would avoid them in the context of C#. "Static type" could too easily be confused with "static class", a class which can only contain static methods. And "dynamic type" can too easily be confused with the dynamic type feature added to C# 4.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it was a book I read the terms *static* and *dynamic* types, and it was a C++ book in the 90s..  Maybe that was just the author's preference.  Probably makes sense in the C++ world since C++ is the least dynamic thing ever..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Virtual methods make C++ actually extremely dynamic. **You don't know what method is going to be called at all at compile time**. The method is going to be chosen "dynamically", based on the runtime type of the receiver.

Comment: Well, my C++ is a bit rusty, but doesn't the compiler construct a vtable with pointers to all the implementations of a virtual method?  So, you're still confined to *some sort of* compile time type.  As opposed to say, JavaScript where you can just write-up an object literal anywhere you want.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Sure, JavaScript is more dynamic. But C++ is far from the least dynamic language out there.

Comment: We might be talking about two different things.  I'm using the word *dynamic* in the same context as *dynamic programming language*.  When I think of a dynamic language, I'm thinking of a type system that can be modified at runtime.  Sure, C++ allows for polymorphism, but the exact behavior of types is constant.  Meaning, the compiler added a little pointer arithmetic into your virtual function call.  What I meant by *least dynamic thing ever* (if you'll look past the hyperbole) is that C++ is quite far from what I'd consider a *dynamic programming language*.

Answer (score 4):

The first is the Declared Type. The second is the Concrete Type.

...at least that's what I call them.

Comment: It seems like my teacher (this was back in the 90s) just made up his own terms too.  His terms would probably now lead to confusion with the rise of dynamically typed languages.